# BodyParser is giving an empty object

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am trying to handle the post routers. I am getting req.body to be an empty object {} using postman
please see my code... I know this has been asked quite a few times. but i couldn't find a solution for myself

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app =express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/register', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

Comment: If you are sending json and not setting the content-type in the header then you should set the body parser to `app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'}));`

Comment: Thanks for the response, @JustCase. I tried it and getting "Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0" is this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With postman, ensure you have one of these two `Content-Type` headers set:

- `application/json`: 
  [You have to select the `JSON` option from the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMQJy.png)
- `x-www-form-urlencoded`:
  [Since you've setup bodyParser to also support urlencoded queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVCDR.png)

If this is not the issue, please do edit your question to include [the `cURL` version of your request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my7yQ.png), for more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the request should be sent with one of the three content-types : raw, json and text.

Try to send request with: content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Not always, some app sends json without content-type, so its api should be able to recognize the data type, there are three ways to define it and they are raws, text and json.  For more read the bodyParser [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: @JustCase Thanks a lot for your clarification. I agree with you. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now before going to the `app.js` first you need to print your req input which is getting into the object or not for that first adjust the form properly in your EJS file to do so,

```
<form action="/yourRoute"  method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="newFriend" placeholder="Name">``
    <button>You just made new friend!</button>
</form>
```

Note: Don't forget to add name to your input i.e `name="newFriend"`

After doing this enter the giving code to your `app.js` file

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

then run your code and watch your prompt!